# GSA get latest results in a collection without q param

Tags: google-search-appliance

I'm trying to get the latest results inserted into a collection (ordered by data) on the homepage. I haven't a 'q' parameter because the user doesn't make a search yet in the homepage. So, there's a way to do this? Maybe a special character, I didn't find anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could utilize the `site:` query to get all content from your site like

```
q=site%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.yoururl.com&sort=date%3AD%3AS%3Ad1
```

(`site:http://www.yoururl.com` URL encoded)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: This is no link but parameter to pass to the system

Comment: Ahhh.  I formatted the link as code, so it doesn't look like a link-only answer.

Comment: Thanks for that, new to all this :)

Comment: Just a note, you could use the as_q parameter (https://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/72/gsa_doc_set/xml_reference/request_format.html#1076795) with an empty q to keep things a little cleaner. So you could have `?q=&as_q=site%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.yoururl.com`, and that way according to q you're still doing an empty search.

Comment: note that you should leave off the trailing `/` from the site like above, so don't use `http://www.yoururl.com/`, use `http://www.yoururl.com` (encoded)

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found this way: I used the parameter `requiredfields` and link to it all the results that I want to show. For example:

```
www.gsa.it/search?q=&sort=date:D:S:d1&requiredfields=client
```

This will return any results that have a meta tag of this name

```
<meta name="client" content="lorem ipsum">
```

[Reference](https://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/72/gsa_doc_set/xml_reference/request_format.html#1076949): Restricts the search results to documents that contain the exact meta tag names or name-value pairs.